# Refinement of two stratifications of an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,\mathscr{O}_{X})$ be a separated $\mathbb{C}$-scheme of finite type.

A locally finite decomposition $X=\coprod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ into locally closed subschemes is said to be a stratification of $X$, if each $X_{i_{0}}$ is smooth and for all $i_{0}\in I$ there exists a subset $I_{i_{0}}\subseteq I$ such that $\overline{X_{i}}=\coprod_{i\in I_{i_{0}}}X_{i}$.

Now given two such stratification $X=\coprod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ and $X=\coprod_{j\in J}Y_{j}$ of $X$, one might wonder whether there exists a stratification $X=\coprod_{k\in K}Z_{k}$ refining both, i.e. each $X_{i}$ and each $Y_{j}$ is a union of some subsets $Z_{k}$ respectively.

The most straightforward candidate seems to me to take the decomposition

> $X=\coprod_{i\in I,j\in J}X_{i}\cap Y_{j}$

into locally closed subsets. Is there any hope that $X_{i}\cap Y_{j}$ can be equipped with the structure of a locally closed subscheme of $X$?

Here are my thoughts about this: If $\mathscr{I}$ and $\mathscr{J}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals of $\mathscr{O}_{X}$
defining $X_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$, one could try to prove that $\mathscr{I}+\mathscr{J}\subseteq\mathscr{O}_{X}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideal defining $X_{i}\cap Y_{j}$. Now we can observe that

> $supp(\mathscr{O}_{X}/\mathscr{I}+\mathscr{J})\subseteq supp(\mathscr{O}_{X}/\mathscr{I})\cap supp(\mathscr{O}_{X}/\mathscr{J})=X_{i}\cap Y_{j}$,

but I don't see if the converse inclusion is true in general.

Am I on the right track and if so, does anyone see how to continue?

Comment: I think what you are writing should be a refined decomposition. I haven't thought thoroughly your approach, but another idea would be to try to use the following: Generally what we take in schemes instead of the intersection is an appropriate fiber product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bit of a can of worms here about stratifications: we want the intersection of any stratum-closures to be a union of stratum-closures. But if we talk about the scheme-theoretic intersection we can get in to some trouble: if we require the intersection to be the reduced union (instead of just asking that the underlying sets agree), then the orbits of $SO(n)$ on $GL(n)/B$ don't form a stratification, which is undesirable. (I originally learned this from Alan Knutson, and he put this in to a comment on StacksBlog [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=3621).) So let me assume we're talking about agreement of underlying sets when we ask for such equalities in this post - this will make our lives a bit easier.

---

The "most straightforwards candidate" in your post is unfortunately not quite correct: we may have to do some extra subdividing. Consider the following two stratifications of $\Bbb A^3$:

- $D(x-yz)$, $V(x-yz)$
- $D(x)$, $V(x)$

It is not difficult to see that these satisfy the assumptions from the question. On the other hand, if we take $\coprod_{i,j} X_i\cap Y_j$, here's what we get:

- $D(x^2-xyz)$
- $D(x)\cap V(x-yz)$
- $D(x-yz)\cap V(x)$
- $V(x,yz)$

and the final piece $V(x,yz)$ is singular. We would need to subdivide this in to smaller pieces (say $V(x,yz)\setminus V(x,y,z)$ and $V(x,y,z)$) to get a stratification satisfying your definition.

---

On the other hand, given any two locally finite stratifications $\coprod Y_j$ and $\coprod Z_k$ of a separated finite type $\Bbb C$-scheme $X$, it is true that there is a locally finite stratification refining both of them.

We make some preliminary observations. First, if $X_1\subset X$ is an irreducible component and we have a locally closed subset $L$ which contains the generic point of $X_1$, then $L$ contains an open subset of $X_1$. This is because a locally closed subset can be written as an intersection of a closed subset and an open subset, and any closed subset containing the generic point must contain all of $X_1$. Next, our scheme $X$ is Noetherian, because it is of finite type over a Noetherian ring. So $X$ has finitely many irreducible components and any locally finite collection of sets is actually globally finite.

Now on to the problem. Write $X=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n$ for the decomposition of $X$ in to irreducible components. For any irreducible component $X_i$ of the collection of points $X_i^\circ$ which belong to only that irreducible component and no others is open. Find a $Y_j$ and $Z_k$ which contain the generic point of $X_i$. By our observation above, each of $Y_j$ and $Z_k$ contain an open subset of $X_i$, and by taking the intersection of these open sets and the smooth locus of $X_i^\circ$ we can find a smooth open subset $W\subset X$ which is contained in $X_i^\circ$, $Y_j$, and $Z_k$ and who's complement inside $X_i$ consists of some finite number of closed subschemes of strictly smaller dimension (here we use that any locally closed subset of a noetherian scheme is again locally noetherian for the finiteness and irreducibility of $X_i$ to say the dimension must drop).

Now observe that in order to give a stratification of $X$ which is a common refinement of $\coprod Y_j$ and $\coprod Z_k$, it is enough to give a stratification of $X\setminus W$ which is a refinement of the stratifications $\coprod (Y_j\cap W^c)$ and $\coprod (Z_k\cap W^c)$. This suggests an inductive approach: consider the collection of maximal-dimensional irreducible components of $X$ and apply the above procedure for all of them. Then at each stage when we go from $X$ to $X\setminus W$, we eliminate one top-dimensional irreducible component at the cost of $X\setminus W$ having potentially finitely many more irreducible components of strictly lower dimension. So after applying this procedure a finite number of times, we get that it's enough to prove the proposition for a scheme of finite type over $\Bbb C$ of strictly smaller dimension. Eventually we get down to a finite discrete union of points, and we can just take the disjoint union of all of these points. So the claim is true.

Comment: Thanks already for the detailed answer. Scheme theory is, however, rather new to me, that's why I still have some trouble to understand the part where you say that the "complement inside Xi consists of some finite number of closed subschemes of strictly smaller dimension". Could someone give a reference to an explanation why this is true?

Comment: @Joo First, the complement of an open subscheme is closed. Next, closed immersions are morphisms of finite type, because affine-locally they're isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A/I\to\operatorname{Spec} A$. As compositions of morphisms of finite type are of finite type, the complement inside $X_i$ is some $\Bbb C$-scheme of finite type, which by the discussion in the post is Noetherian and thus has finitely many irreducible components. As for the dimension, if $Z\subset X$ is a proper closed subspace of an irreducible (fd) topological space then it has smaller dimension almost by definition.